# How to create a Gantt chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I want to create the following picture in LaTeX. I did search a lot but I didn't find anything about Gantt chart.

[image]

Comment: try `pgfgantt` package

Comment: It's called a "Gannt Chart", not a Project Bar Graph or Project Bar Time.

Comment: Ok, the title was corrected.

Comment: pgfgantt is a nice way to typeset Gantt charts, but not a very nice one to create and manage projects. I wish software like https://www.ganttproject.biz could export to pgfgantt

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think a Gantt Chart is the way to go by looking at your example, using the [`pgfgantt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) package. I don't make them as fancy as your example, but I believe you can get quite close with solely using this package. As an example, here is the Gantt Charts I quickly define for projects:
[image]

I think I spent about one hour creating the 'template' for this setup and to adjust it for a current project, filling it requires about ten minutes of work.
However, making one as beautiful as you listed would require a lot more time in creating a nice template instead of the basic one I showed here. Perhaps using a combination of [`pgfgantt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) and [`tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) will get you there, but I can't help you further than that.

Maybe you'll spend a long time defining a beautiful template, but once you got it down it's easy to use for future projects.

---

### Edit : Code of my example

As requested in the comments, here is the code I used for my Gantt Chart. The type of bars and such are defined in the preamble. I defined the grid and general layout in the options of the ganttchart command ( `\begin{ganttchart}[options]` ). Afterwards I just fill the grid with bars, and then I link them all up.

It's a pretty basic setup, but it lets me use dates to insert into the grid which (in my case) is really useful as I usually have the dates written somewhere else on a timeline. Then I link the right elements and draw a group above elements that belong together (in the example, the orange, blue and green lines).

So whenever I make a new gantt chart I have the same code listed here without anything between `\begin{ganttchart}[options]` and `\end{ganttchart}`, then I adjust the grid's date to match mine, and then I start filling it with bars, links and groups.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
%Used to draw gantt charts, which I will use for the calendar.
%Let's define some awesome new ganttchart elements:
\newganttchartelement{orangebar}{
    orangebar/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=red!66!black,
        very thick,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=orange!80
    },
    orangebar label font=\slshape,
    orangebar left shift=.1,
    orangebar right shift=-.1
}

\newganttchartelement{bluebar}{
    bluebar/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=purple!44!black,
        very thick,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!80
    },
    bluebar label font=\slshape,
    bluebar left shift=.1,
    bluebar right shift=-.1
}

\newganttchartelement{greenbar}{
    greenbar/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=green!50!black,
        very thick,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=green!80
    },
    greenbar label font=\slshape,
    greenbar left shift=.1,
    greenbar right shift=-.1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    hgrid style/.style={black, dotted},
    vgrid={*5{black,dotted}, *1{white, dotted}, *1{black, dashed}},
    x unit=3mm,
    y unit chart=9mm,
    y unit title=12mm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    group label font=\bfseries \Large,
    link/.style={->, thick}
    ]{2014-09-22}{2014-12-21}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week}\\

    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=orange}
    ]{IMKL Reader}{2014-09-22}{2014-11-9}\\ [grid]
    \ganttorangebar[
        name=Documentation
    ]{Documentation}{2014-09-23}{2014-09-23}\\ [grid]
    \ganttorangebar[
        name=FMETutorial
    ]{FME Tutorial}{2014-09-24}{2014-09-26}\\ [grid]
    \ganttorangebar[
        name=FME
    ]{FME}{2014-09-30}{2014-10-03}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2014-10-7}{2014-10-10}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2014-10-14}{2014-10-15}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2014-10-17}{2014-10-17}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar[name=FMEend]{}{2014-10-21}{2014-10-24}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2014-10-28}{2014-10-31}\\ [grid]
    \ganttorangebar[name=Manual]{Manual}{2014-10-30}{2014-10-31}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2014-11-4}{2014-11-7} \ganttnewline[thick, black]

    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=blue}
    ]{Test Cases}{2014-10-27}{2014-11-9}
    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=blue}
    ]{}{2014-11-17}{2014-12-19}\\ [grid]
    \ganttbluebar{Innocent testing}{2014-10-30}{2014-10-31}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar[name=Innocent]{}{2014-11-4}{2014-11-7}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-12-4}{2014-12-5}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-12-9}{2014-12-10}\\ [grid]
    \ganttbluebar{Test Case Testing}{2014-11-6}{2014-11-7}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-11-18}{2014-11-19}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-11-24}{2014-11-27}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-12-1}{2014-12-4}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-12-10}{2014-12-10}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-12-16}{2014-12-16}\\ [grid]
    \ganttbluebar[name=Writing]{Writing}{2014-11-18}{2014-11-19}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-11-24}{2014-11-28} 
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-12-4}{2014-12-4} 
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-12-10}{2014-12-10}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2014-12-16}{2014-12-16}\ganttnewline[thick, black]

    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=green}
    ]{KLIP Manager}{2014-11-3}{2014-11-9}
    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=green}
    ]{}{2014-11-17}{2014-11-23}\\ [grid]
    \ganttgreenbar{Manual}{2014-11-4}{2014-11-7}
    \ganttlinkedgreenbar{}{2014-11-18}{2014-11-19}

    %Implementing links
    \ganttlink[link mid=0.75]{Documentation}{FME}
    \ganttlink{FMETutorial}{FME}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your example. Could you please share code so that it can benefit to others?

Comment: @ebo, I added my code for my gantt chart. For more detailed information though I suggest reading the `pgfgantt` documentation as this is a pretty basic template.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to translate the names of the months and other labels into a language other than English, such as Spanish? I tried using your example code by adding `babel` and even using the `\selectlanguage` command. But nothing works.

Comment: Maybe [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351330/changing-language-of-weeks-and-months-in-pgfgantt) can help you out?