# Fitting large table after using Excel2Latex

Tags: tables, tabularx, landscape, excel2latex

I'm working on my thesis document and I have a large schedule table that i did for the plannig of my project. I want to put it on a horizontal page in the annexes section, but I have several problems.

1. The table is too big, even though that the page is horizontal
2. The landscape environment rotates also the page number
3. I have this error

`Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.10 ...lticolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{N°}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\mu... Your command was ignored. Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command, or <return> to continue without it.`

Here is my code

```
    \documentclass[11pt, hidelinks, letterpaper,openany]{book} 
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{pdflscape} 
    \usepackage[margin = 3cm, vmargin=2.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lscape} %Orientación de las hojas
    \usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow, longtable, colortbl}

\begin{document}
\section*{ANEXO}

\begin{landscape}
%Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Hoja1'
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{N°}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{Actividad}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Mes} & \multicolumn{4}{p{21.42em}|}{Agosto} & \multicolumn{4}{p{21.42em}|}{Septiembre} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Octubre}  & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Noviembre}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Diciembre} \\
\cmidrule{3-22}          &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Semana} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} \\
\cmidrule{3-22}          &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Fecha} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1-4}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{7-11}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{14-18 }} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{14-18 }} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1-8}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{11-15}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{18-22}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{25-29}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{2-6}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{9-13}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{16-20}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{23-31}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1-3}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{6-10}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{13-17}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{20-24}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{27-30}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1-8}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{11-15}} \\
\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Duración (Semanas)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    1     & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Ajuste del sistema y validación} & 5     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}\textcolor[rgb]{ .753,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{5.355em}|}{1.1} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Aval del comité de ética } & 4     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{5.355em}|}{1.2} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Pruebas con sujetos para la validación } & 2     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    1,3   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Sistema final } & 1     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    2     & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Elaboración PCB señales digitales} & 6     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    2,1   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Esquemático y PCB} & 2     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    2,2   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Fabricación y ensamblaje} & 3     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    2,3   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Carcasa} & 1     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    3     & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Análisis de señales MPS} & 14    & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    3,1   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Revisión bibliográfica } & 9     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    3,2   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Análisis de señales} & 4     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    3,3   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Resultados y conclusiones} & 3     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &       &       &  \\
    4     & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Elaboración Documento Final} & 11    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} \\
    \midrule
    4,1   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Introducción - Metodología} & 4     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    4,2   & Resultados  & 3     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    4,3   & Discusión & 2     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &  \\
    \midrule
    4,4   & Restante & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &  \\
    \midrule
    4,5   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Revisión y ajustes finales} & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &  \\
    \midrule
    4,6   & Entrega & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

And my output

[image]

It should look like this

[image]

Thanks for your help,

Juan

Comment: You might consider rewriting the schedule as [a regular Gannt chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344323/how-to-create-a-gantt-chart).

Comment: @MikeRenfro Yeah, I think that is the best solution. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ° (U+B0)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX
```

so add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\textsuperscript{o}}
```

to the preamble.

The table was over wide mostly as teh headings were forced to be wide by the `p` columns so I changed those to `l`, and reduced the font size.

It doesn't look pretty but now it fits you can adjust the column widths as you wish.

```
    \documentclass[11pt, hidelinks, letterpaper,openany]{book} 
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{pdflscape} 
    \usepackage[margin = 3cm, vmargin=2.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lscape} %Orientación de las hojas
    \usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow, longtable, colortbl}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\textsuperscript{o}}
\begin{document}
\section*{ANEXO}

\begin{landscape}
%Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Hoja1'
\begin{table}
\tiny
\vspace{-40pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{N°}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{Actividad}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Mes} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Agosto} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Septiembre} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Octubre}  & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Noviembre}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Diciembre} \\
\cmidrule{3-22}          &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Semana} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} \\
\cmidrule{3-22}          &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Fecha} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1-4}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{7-11}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{14-18 }} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{14-18 }} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1-8}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{11-15}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{18-22}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{25-29}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{2-6}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{9-13}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{16-20}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{23-31}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1-3}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{6-10}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{13-17}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{20-24}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{27-30}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1-8}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{11-15}} \\
\cmidrule{3-3}          &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Duración (Semanas)} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    1     & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Ajuste del sistema y validación} & 5     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}\textcolor[rgb]{ .753,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{5.355em}|}{1.1} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Aval del comité de ética } & 4     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{5.355em}|}{1.2} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Pruebas con sujetos para la validación } & 2     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    1,3   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Sistema final } & 1     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    2     & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Elaboración PCB señales digitales} & 6     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    2,1   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Esquemático y PCB} & 2     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    2,2   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Fabricación y ensamblaje} & 3     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    2,3   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Carcasa} & 1     & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    3     & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Análisis de señales MPS} & 14    & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    3,1   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Revisión bibliográfica } & 9     & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    3,2   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Análisis de señales} & 4     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    3,3   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Resultados y conclusiones} & 3     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &       &       &  \\
    4     & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Elaboración Documento Final} & 11    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .608,  .761,  .902} \\
    \midrule
    4,1   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Introducción - Metodología} & 4     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    4,2   & Resultados  & 3     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    4,3   & Discusión & 2     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &  \\
    \midrule
    4,4   & Restante & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &       &  \\
    \midrule
    4,5   & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}|}{Revisión y ajustes finales} & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} &  \\
    \midrule
    4,6   & Entrega & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .816,  .557} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!. It did the trick, but I think I will rewrite it as a Gantt chart. It might display better.