# How to use pdfgantt in other language rather than english?

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, pgfgantt

I was following the beautiful instructions for building a Gantt Chart ([How to create a Gantt chart?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344323/how-to-create-a-gantt-chart/344324)), and I was doing great. Nevertheless, I've noticed that if I try to use SPANISH as a language ( including \usepackage[spanish]{babel} ) it won't compile. Any ideas of what to do? I assume that the babel package is causing some trouble, what should I do if I want 'septiembre' instead of 'September'?

Here is my sourcecode:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
%Used to draw gantt charts, which I will use for the calendar.
%Let's define some awesome new ganttchart elements:
\newganttchartelement{orangebar}{
    orangebar/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=red!66!black,
        very thick,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=orange!80
    },
    orangebar label font=\slshape,
    orangebar left shift=.1,
    orangebar right shift=-.1
}

\newganttchartelement{bluebar}{
    bluebar/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=purple!44!black,
        very thick,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!80
    },
    bluebar label font=\slshape,
    bluebar left shift=.1,
    bluebar right shift=-.1
}

\newganttchartelement{greenbar}{
    greenbar/.style={
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw=green!50!black,
        very thick,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=green!80
    },
    greenbar label font=\slshape,
    greenbar left shift=.1,
    greenbar right shift=-.1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    hgrid style/.style={black, dotted},
    vgrid={*5{black,dotted}, *1{white, dotted}, *1{black, dashed}},
    x unit=3mm,
    y unit chart=9mm,
    y unit title=12mm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    group label font=\bfseries \Large,
    link/.style={->, thick}
    ]{2020-09-22}{2020-12-21}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week}\\

    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=orange}
    ]{IMKL Reader}{2020-09-22}{2020-11-9}\\ [grid]
    \ganttorangebar[
        name=Documentation
    ]{Documentation}{2020-09-23}{2020-09-23}\\ [grid]
    \ganttorangebar[
        name=FMETutorial
    ]{FME Tutorial}{2020-09-24}{2020-09-26}\\ [grid]
    \ganttorangebar[
        name=FME
    ]{FME}{2020-09-30}{2020-10-03}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2020-10-7}{2020-10-10}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2020-10-14}{2020-10-15}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2020-10-17}{2020-10-17}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar[name=FMEend]{}{2020-10-21}{2020-10-24}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2020-10-28}{2020-10-31}\\ [grid]
    \ganttorangebar[name=Manual]{Manual}{2020-10-30}{2020-10-31}
    \ganttlinkedorangebar{}{2020-11-4}{2020-11-7} \ganttnewline[thick, black]

    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=blue}
    ]{Test Cases}{2020-10-27}{2020-11-9}
    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=blue}
    ]{}{2020-11-17}{2020-12-19}\\ [grid]
    \ganttbluebar{Innocent testing}{2020-10-30}{2020-10-31}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar[name=Innocent]{}{2020-11-4}{2020-11-7}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-12-4}{2020-12-5}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-12-9}{2020-12-10}\\ [grid]
    \ganttbluebar{Test Case Testing}{2020-11-6}{2020-11-7}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-11-18}{2020-11-19}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-11-24}{2020-11-27}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-12-1}{2020-12-4}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-12-10}{2020-12-10}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-12-16}{2020-12-16}\\ [grid]
    \ganttbluebar[name=Writing]{Writing}{2020-11-18}{2020-11-19}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-11-24}{2020-11-28} 
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-12-4}{2020-12-4} 
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-12-10}{2020-12-10}
    \ganttlinkedbluebar{}{2020-12-16}{2020-12-16}\ganttnewline[thick, black]

    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=green}
    ]{KLIP Manager}{2020-11-3}{2020-11-9}
    \ganttgroup[
        group/.append style={fill=green}
    ]{}{2020-11-17}{2020-11-23}\\ [grid]
    \ganttgreenbar{Manual}{2020-11-4}{2020-11-7}
    \ganttlinkedgreenbar{}{2020-11-18}{2020-11-19}

    %Implementing links
    \ganttlink[link mid=0.75]{Documentation}{FME}
    \ganttlink{FMETutorial}{FME}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! In this case `\usetikzlibary{babel}` does not seem to have the desired effect, but what you can do is to load two languages: `\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}` and add before  `\begin{ganttchart}`: `\selectlanguage{english}` and after `\end{ganttchart}` you may add `\selectlanguage{spanish}`.

Answer (score 2):

`pgfgantt` is based on the `pgfcalendar` package.

Regarding localization issues `pgfmanual` says:

> All textual representations of week days or months (like “Monday” or “February”) are wrapped with `\translate` commands from the `translator` package (if this package is not loaded, no translation takes place). Furthermore, the `pgfcalendar` package will try to load the `translator-months-dictionary`, if the `translator` package is loaded.

Replacing

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

with

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{translator}
```

in your file should do it.